# With Mysql - Return the output of AES_ENCRYPT as string "0x8DBADD..."

Tags: mysql

In Mysql the function AES_ENCRYPT() returns a hex like:

```
0x8DBADD32FD0FAB62232104DEB9D56246
```

How can I return it as string:

```
"0x8DBADD32FD0FAB62232104DEB9D56246"
```

so for example I can right() to remove the first two characters: "0x"

I tried CAST but that converts the HEX to string. What I need is the string literal of the Hex

Comment: What I mean is 0x8DBADD32FD0FAB62232104DEB9D56246 as "0x8DBADD32FD0FAB62232104DEB9D56246" so I can remove the 0X using a simple left()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) to make the conversion and [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to add the prefix:

```
SELECT CONCAT('0x', HEX(0x8DBADD32FD0FAB62232104DEB9D56246)) AS hex_dump;
```